# How do I stop http automatically going to https?

Tags: django

When redirecting from a home page to another page I continuously get "You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP." Out of the two buttons that redirect only one provides this issue, and the other redirects fine.

[image: Code in vscode]

[image: Browser error]

I've tried setting SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT to false in settings.py however I still get this error.

Answer (score 2):

- Use a different browser that doesn't always redirect to HTTPS
- Configure your proxy to not redirect to HTTPS for the development server.

  - proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;